# Wordpress multisite proper prefix attribution

Tags: multisite

I have installed a multisite network successfully using the sub-directory method. I created the first 3 blogs without a problem ( **prefix_2_  , prefix_3_** ) . I then needed to create a 4th one to test a functionality (**prefix_4_** ).

After testing the functionality I deleted the 4th blog (prefix_4_ ) and created another one to replace it. WP registered it as prefix_5_ . I deleted it again and recreated yet another testing one (prefix_6_ ).

I am wondering how Wordpress determines we are at prefix_6_ and how I can reset that so that I don't jump  from **prefix_3_** to **prefix_6_** in the database. Blog count shows 4 but Wordpress continues to increment the prefix numbe rregardless of how many blogs were deleted.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: the numbers are meaningless, just don't look or try to figure any sequence in them, assume they are totally random

Comment: Hi Mark, I understand they are meaningless, but when you are managing a network of 600 blogs, there may be a reason to keep things neat

Comment: control your OCD and don't look at the DB ;)

Comment: Not funny Mark. The main reason I asked was actually that I have a custom installation that is very large and runs with Laravel. So, this is not your typical blog SADkey !

Comment: sorry, but if you don't have millions of sites it it not large, and if you had you would not be able to look at the DB, or to run any script to "compact" it

Comment: btw, the official definition of "large" in the code is more then 10000 sites

Comment: If you enjoy accusing pple of having OCD for asking a simple question, you should get over yourself. No less for a genius who can't differentiate "then" from "than"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using a DB level "auto increment" flag on the base site `blogs` table.  Basically, when a new record is inserted into the table the blog id number is automatically created with no discrete SQL -- it just "happens".

The database keeps an internal control structure for this that you don't have direct access to.  Even if you delete a row that internal counter does not change and the next insertion is simply +1 from the last one.  Unless you turn off auto-increment for that primary key on the table, which would be a bad thing to do.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884387/how-to-override-the-attribution-of-an-auto-incrementing-primary-key-when-inserti) for additional details.

WP gets the new blog id from the [insert_blog()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/insert_blog/) call, which does not seem to allow the caller to specify a suggested or desired id number.  You'd either need to write your own version of the functions that effect the instantiation of a new blog (not recommended), or try to live with this default behavior (recommended).

Comment: Thanks CC. I had found the answer but appreciate the input which is spot on

Comment: this is mostly correct in practice, but should not be relied on. The only required property of the blog specific table is uniqueness, and when using multisite on several DBs for a very big site, this might or might not hold true depending on how they distribute the sites between the servers. In addition, there is nothing to prevent you from changing the logic if you really need "compactness", it is just not trivial, but there is nothing conceptually wrong with it.